# Doctrine isDeletable method in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a Entity in my database (say Member) which has many relationships with other tables  (6 relationships to be exact). Some of them I don't want mapped with the ORM (I mean linked to this Entity) because they may have many records (like MemberAccessLogs for example) and some other load many other entities.

Now I want this Member Entity to have an isDeletable method so I can disable exclude button in administration page.

If I where to do this the traditional way, I would have to declare the associations with all the other tables in the entity class, including MemberAccessLogs and I would put the method in it so I could test if these associations are empty.

But AFAIU, I would have to make a fetch (or at least a count) to the association's tables in order check for empty.

Another way would be to fetch the Members I want shown and then make a separate query to check for empty with a low cost exists(select * from table limit 1) in these sub-tables and then populate the isDeletable method in Member programmatically before pass it to Twig.

But I found this solution cumbersome. Anyone has a better way to do this ?

Just for the record: Some people may think this is "premature optimization". I maintain (contrary to some), that you should think ahead when you are programming and don't this this is bad. But I really think this isn't the place to discuss it. Please let's focus on the question asked ok ? :)

**Edit**

To easily prove that limit 1 is increadibly faster than count, I did a small test in a table in my database that has more than 20 million lines. Here are the results:

```
select count(*) from loga [20 million+ table]
20678473
1 row(s) fetched - 27023ms

select exists(select null from loga limit 1) 
true
1 row(s) fetched - 2ms
```

I guess 13511,5 times faster is conclusive enough. :D

Comment: I don't see how a `select * from table limit 1` is more efficient then a `count(*) from table`.

Comment: Included edit on this subject on the question.

Comment: If you're into contributing (and even if not), please consider to create a PR to have `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::isEmpty()` do as you describe. It looks like that could be quite an optimazation. The solution to your problem would also become easier ;)

Comment: OK. I'm in. The problem is time. But I'll check that on tuesday when I get back to work. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Extra lazy

You could look into [extra-lazy associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html).

Basically you map all associations as you normally would, and add `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"`:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class CmsGroup
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="CmsUser", mappedBy="groups", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    public $users;
}
```

Now Doctrine will *not* load the *complete* collection into memory the first time it's accessed, but performs specialized queries to load the *parts* you actually need at that moment.

So `$users->count()` (or `count($users)`) on the collection would trigger a simple count-query in stead of loading the complete collection into memory.

#### PostLoad

You could use an [`postLoad`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload) event to determine if such an entity is deletable. This `postLoad` event is called after an entity is constructed by the EntityManager, so when the entity is loaded.

Add an unmapped property (`$isDeletable`) to the entity that stores whether the entity can be deleted or not.

Create an [entity listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) that listens to the `postLoad` event. The listener can have the EntityManager, DBAL Connection, or anything else injected. With that dependency you could perform whatever query you want and use the result to set `$isDeletable`.

The result is a single additional query when the entity is loaded, after which the entity "knows" whether it's deletable or not.

An example of using the `postLoad` event can found in a [Cookbook entry on the Strategy Pattern](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/strategy-cookbook-introduction.html)

Do note that when the conditions that determine whether it's deletable or not change, the value of `$isDeletable` could become incorrect. To resolve this issue, you could keep track of those conditions:

#### Keep track

Add a *mapped* property (`$isDeletable`) to the entity that stores whether the entity can be deleted or not. It would probably start with `true`.

When something is added to an association which would mean that the entity is no longer deletable, set `$isDeletable` to `false`.

When something is removed from an association that which would mean that the entity is deletable again, set `$isDeletable` to `true`.

In other words: with every change you keep track of whether the entity is deletable or not.

This way you won't need any additional queries at all.

There's a [Cookbook entry on aggregate fields](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html) that explains this concept very well.

Comment: Extra-lazy associations as you said still use count. Which in my opinion is the wrong way to do it. In a large table, count is still very costly. As I already said once in Doctrine's mail list it would be much better if this was done using exists(select null from subtable limit 1). "limit 1" is instantaneous in every db that supports it. So that's why I prefer not to use Extra lazy associations.

Comment: Keep track would introduce an increased level of complexity that I don't think it fits a POPO. But that OnLoad thing I didn't knew. Do you mean I can put DQL or Native SQL on the Entity itself ? I couldn't find any docs or examples about it. Can you point me to some ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, the "onLoad" section is a bit more in depth now. Also, the event is actually **postLoad**, sorry for that!

Comment: Offtopic: I don't agree that entities should be treated as POPO's. I would highly recommend you to watch the talk [Unbreakable domain models](http://verraes.net/2013/06/unbreakable-domain-models/) by Mathias Verraes. IMHO an entity is the _only correct place_ to put the "keep track" logic.

Comment: Yout approach is very interesting. I'll test that as soon as I got back to work. And I'll check the talk also.

Comment: Took a good look at eventlisteners and it's a very good solution. Thanks for that. Award granted. :)
About the talk I have seen it and also considered it very useful. Thank you again.